# matching dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets, x and y. Basically want R to scan the first two columns in dataset x and dataset y and if both character strings are found in either of the first two columns in dataset y to then return that record and associated third column.

example x dataset:

```
speciesA    speciesB
species22   species11
species33   species44
species44   species44
...
```

example y dataset:

```
speciesA    speciesB    dist
species11   species22   9
species33   species44   14
species55   species33   5
...
```

desired output:

```
speciesA    speciesB    dist
species11   species22   9
species33   species44   14
```

Comment: What do the two columns mean? And why are species flipped sometimes?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
output <- merge(x = x, y = y, by = c('speciesA', 'speciesB'), all.x = F, all.y = F)
output <- output[, c('speciesA', 'speciesB', 'dist')]) # column order
```

Comment: That works but the first two columns it turns out are not in the same order (i.e. speciesA and speciesB are sometimes reversed, although the rows are still preserved such the character strings are still on the same row just that the first two columns are flipped in some cases)

Comment: I expanded the answer; are we talking about the same problem?

Comment: I changed my question

Comment: Please: dont just drop code. Give a bit of explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr library has a nice join workflow:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(speciesA = c("species11", "species33", "species44"),
                speciesB = c("species22", "species44", "species44"))

y <- data.frame(speciesA = c("species11", "species33", "species55"),
                speciesB = c("species22", "species44", "species33"),
                dist = c(9, 14, 5))

output <- inner_join(x, y)
```

produces:

```
> output
   speciesA  speciesB dist
1 species11 species22    9
2 species33 species44   14
```

Answer (score 0):

First, how to create a TRULY reproducible example:

```
x <- data.frame(spA=c('species22','species33','species44'),
                spB=c('species11','species44','species44'),
                stringsAsFactors=F)
y <- data.frame(spA=c('species11','species33','species55'),
                spB=c('species22','species44','species33'),
                dist=c(9,14,5),
                stringsAsFactors=F)
x
y
```

Then, a function to paste the two species from each dataframe in alphabetical order, creating a new column, and then merge both dataframes by this new column.

```
pasteSorted <- function(spp) {
  return(paste0(sort(spp),collapse=','))
}
x$spp <- apply(x[,1:2],1,pasteSorted)
y$spp <- apply(y[,1:2],1,pasteSorted)
x
y
z <- merge(x,y,by='spp')
```

Finally, remove the unnecessary columns, and rename the others.

```
z <- z[,-(1:3)]
names(z) <- c('spA','spB','dist')
z
```